# How to read all integers into array from input file in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, file

So let's say I have a file like this:
1 23
14
abc
20

It will read the numbers 1, 23, 14, but I also want it to read the value 20 into the array.
How can I accomplish this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 1000;
    int numbers[ARRAY_SIZE], count = 0;
    double total = 0, average;

    ifstream inputFile;

    if(argc == 2){
        inputFile.open(argv[1]);
    }
    else{ 
        cout << "Invalid" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    while (count < ARRAY_SIZE && inputFile >> numbers[count]){
         count++;
    }
    inputFile.close();
    ...
```

Comment: Please search this site for *C++ read integers from file into array* - there are literally dozens of existing posts that demonstrate doing so. You should always do a thorough search of this site before asking a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it. I added comments to the code to explain the intent and used a `std::vector<int>` instead of an array with a hardcoded size since you didn't mention any restrictions and I feel it is a better way to handle the problem. If you must used a statically sized array you should be able to adapt this.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

// Avoid using namespace std;

std::vector<int> readData(std::istream& input)
{
    // In general prefer std::vector for variable sized data
    std::vector<int> ret;
    std::string word;
    std::stringstream ss;

    while (input >> word)
    {
        // Clear error flags and set the conversion stream to the value read.
        ss.clear();
        ss.str(word);

        int val = 0;
        // The first condition will fail if the string doesn't start with a digit
        // The second will fail if there is still data in the stream after some of
        // it was converted.
        if (ss >> val && ss.eof())
        {
            ret.push_back(val);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    // In your code open the file and pass the stream to
    // the function instead of std::cin
    auto v = readData(std::cin);
    for (auto n : v)
    {
        std::cout << n << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

```
Input: 1 23 14 abc 20 123xyz 50 nope 12345 a 100
Output: 1 23 14 20 50 12345 100
```

Working example: https://godbolt.org/z/ab87KjzjK

Comment: Upvoted. That `ss.clear()` on line 19 is unnecessary.

Comment: @Dúthomhas I thought that too, but without it every number after the first fails. I figured `str(newData)` would reset `eof` like `seekg` does but it doesn't seem to and I wasn't able to find any documentation that mentioned it. Probably best to move the `stringstream` inside the while loop. *shrug*

Comment: Oop! Yes, I _**totally**_ misread that. Yes, you _**do**_ need the `ss.clear()` to reuse the stringstream every iteration. (I misread that you were clearing state flags on the `input` stream.) And yes, better to move `ss` _inside_ the loop. _Mia culpa!_

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for this.

```
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::string buffer = " 1 23 14 abc 20";
    std::regex rx(R"((?:^|\s)([+-]?[[:digit:]]+(?:\.[[:digit:]]+)?)(?=$|\s))"); // Declare the regex with a raw string literal
    std::smatch m;
    std::string str = buffer;
    while (regex_search(str, m, rx)) {
        std::cout << "Number found: " << m[1] << std::endl; // Get Captured Group 1 text
        str = m.suffix().str(); // Proceed to the next match
    }  
    return 0;
}
```